# What's the best way to convert "awk '{print $2 >> $1}' file" in a Perl one-liner?

Tags: perl, awk

How could I convert:

```
awk '{print $2 >> $1}' file
```

in a short Perl one-liner?

"file" could look like this:

> fruit      banana
>   vegetable  beetroot
>   vegetable  carrot
>   mushroom   chanterelle
>   fruit      apple

Comment: Why do you want to?  What improvement are you wanting to see in the Perl version over the Awk one?

Comment: I found a similar awk-oneliner on stackoverflow. For me it looks very beautiful and in my eyes in this case there is no improvement with Perl. A long time ago I learned a little awk, but I don't remember enough to use it. Therefore my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not pure Perl, but you can do:

```
perl -nae '`echo $F[1] >> $F[0]`' input_file
```

Comment: For small, quick-and-dirty jobs I would take this one. I hope nobody will tar and feather me because I didn't choose an answer with a pure Perl solution.

Answer (score 5):

there may some other ways, but here's what i can think of

```
perl -ane 'open(FILE,">>",$F[0]); print FILE $F[1];close(FILE);' file
```

Comment: Name can change but the quality of answers remain the same :)

Answer (score 4):

I guess awk has to be better at some things :-)

This is right at the limit of what I'd do on the command line, but it avoids reopening filehandles.

```
$ perl -lane '$fh{$F[0]} || open $fh{$F[0]}, ">>", $F[0]; print {$fh{$F[0]}} $F[1]' file
```

Comment: as I understand it, this is what awk does.

Answer (score 1):

This is what `a2p <<< '{print $2 >> $1}'` produces

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
    if $running_under_some_shell;
                        # this emulates #! processing on NIH machines.
                        # (remove #! line above if indigestible)

eval '$'.$1.'$2;' while $ARGV[0] =~ /^([A-Za-z_0-9]+=)(.*)/ && shift;
                        # process any FOO=bar switches

$, = ' ';               # set output field separator
$\ = "\n";              # set output record separator

while (<>) {
    ($Fld1,$Fld2) = split(' ', $_, -1);
    &Pick('>>', $Fld1) &&
        (print $fh $Fld2);
}

sub Pick {
    local($mode,$name,$pipe) = @_;
    $fh = $name;
    open($name,$mode.$name.$pipe) unless $opened{$name}++;
}
```